# Remove quotes from MongoTemplate query with $in clause

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have mongoTemplate query with a combination of various criterias. In this query I need to select documents by a collection of Ids. So I use "in" method.

Here is my code:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("sizeId").is(sizeId));

query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("companyId").in(companyIds));

List<StatisticUnit> result = mongoTemplate.find(query, StatisticUnit.class);
```

"companyIds" is a List of Integer values.

I've got no result because MongoTemplate wraps $in operator arguments in qoutes so that Mongo consider them as Strings. Real query looks like this:

```
$in: ["5", "15"]
```

instead of

```
$in: [5, 15]
```

How to tell mongoTemplate not to ignore a type of collection values and not to wrap them in quotes in case of Integer? Thanks!

Comment: companyIds what kind of type is ?, Collection<?>

Comment: what is the type of "companyId" in your @Document annotated class? Which I guess might be StatisticUnit. Should be Integer

Comment: companyIds is an ArrayList<Integer>, companyId in StatisticUnit class has an Integer type.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was about Collection type.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by myself. When I use HashSet instead of ArrayList everything goes ok. Hope this helps someone else.